# Proper notation for subset/selection from a vector

Tags: notation, vectors

I have a column **X** vector which is the result of some calculations. **X** is comprised of N+M elements, where the first N elements are electrical voltages and the last M elements are currents.
\begin{equation}
 X = \begin{bmatrix}
      V\\
      I\\
    \end{bmatrix} 
\end{equation}

Following this, I wish to use only the *last M* elements of **X** in some further calculations, but I am not sure how to write it correctly. How do I denote that I want only the elements of the **I** vector?
I could write an intermediate step such as $$P = [X_{N+1},...,X_{N+M}]$$ but I wasn't sure if there was a sleek way of writing it all in one step.

Is there an accepted notation for this?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:

I would use the notation $I$. There is no danger of confusion.

Additional remark: The reason there is no danger is that you have nicely prefaced your $X\,= [\,]$ statement with clear words explaining what you are up to.